# Make camera fill full screen

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language

I've got a kivy app and I'd like to make the camera component fill the entire screen as the background. Here's what I've currently got:

```
<CamBoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    display: entry
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        id: entry
        multiline: False
        Camera:
            center: self.size and entry.center
            size: entry.height, entry.width

            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix:
                Rotate:
                    angle: 90
                    origin: self.center

            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix:
            allow_stretch: True
            resolution: (720, 1080)
            play: True
```

but the camera just fills part of the screen, it hides behind any button though, so that's good.
Thanks, Ed.

Comment: you could start with a floatlayout, add your camera widget and set it to fill the full screen, next add a BoxLayout which will be drawn above the camera widget and set it to fill the full screen again... et voila

Comment: Hate to be a nuisance, but how do I set it to fill the full screen?

Comment: by full screen I mean the whole window of the app. Sorry I wasn't precise. Something like size: window.size.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, been a tad hectic. I tried `size: window.size` but it cam back with the error: `NameError: name 'window' is not defined`

Comment: how about `size: app.root.size`?

Comment: That came back with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: @EdLynch  Hi, have you figured out how to get camera fill the entire screen ? I've got camera set to resolution of 1280x720 but it shows up as a narrow rectangle instead of spreading over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here, and I still posted a question like yours in the portuguese version of stack overflow. The code bellow worked for me, try it:

```
Camera:
   resolution: (self.width, self.height)
```

It returns some errors like the written bellow but the video seems perfect:

```
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
```

I still don't know if these errors are worrisome...

Answer (score 0):

```
allow_stretch: True
keep_ratio:False
```

Add these codes to Camera properties.